# How to interact with disks or cd-roms in Protected Mode?

Tags: linux, operating-system, driver, device-driver

I am trying to write a hobby experiment OS now. And I am having this problem.

In Real Mode, I can rely on BIOS to deal with disks and cd-roms (sometimes LBA BIOS extenstion is used). But once I enter the Protected Mode, I cannot use BIOS interrupt any more. So, should I write my own device driver? Is there any best practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are several approaches:

- virtualize the BIOS interface in protected mode
- write your own protected mode driver
- don't support the drives

Granted, the last one isn't great for general-purpose systems, but it has its uses, like in the military product I am currently working on—they don't want removable media for security reasons.

Writing your own driver has several advantages:

- The BIOS interface is a "busy wait" implementation.  Every BIOS disk access will stall all processes in your O/S.
- Also, drive i/o is one of several abstraction layers, many of which are much more complex to realize a filesystem.
- You need not start from scratch.  Begin with the Linux disk drivers.  See [this](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As to your military product, if it doesn's support drives, where would it boot from? And where would it load programs to run?

Comment: From non-removable media: flash memory soldered in place.  Programs are resident in the NVRAM, but there is an explicit, password-protected mechanism for updates through a serial link.